# How to integrate adyen payment getaway in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adyen

Can we integrate adyen payment getaway in eclipse?

Any one has idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a number of useful examples on GitHub:

- https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-cse-android
- https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-checkout-android
- https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-dl-android

Does this help you?

Comment: Yes, I check this links but it is for android studio not for eclipse

Comment: So, now i converted my project eclipse to android studio. now no need sdk for eclipse. Thank you uselight for suggestions..